# Converting code from NHibernate 2.x to 3.x

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am playing with NHibernate and trying to create a generic `Repository` using this [article](http://daniel.wertheim.se/2009/11/04/nhibernate-repository-pattern/).
The article is using the NHibernate 2.x, and am using the 3.x version.
i want to convert the following code but i want to verify that the execution remain the same.
**Original code**

```
public IList<T> GetListBy<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query = null)
{
    return InnerSession.Linq<T>().Where(query).ToList();
}
```

**Converted code**

```
 public T GetItemBy<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query) where T : class
 {
     return (T)InnerSession.QueryOver<T>().Where(query);  //.SingleOrDefault(query);
 }
```

Is it the right conversion ?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use LINQ, the correct conversion is:

```
return InnerSession.Query<T>().Where(query).ToList();
```

`Query<T>()` is an extension method in a different namespace (NHibernate.Linq).

Comment: QueryOver works fine if no linq is required. But you should add the `List()` method to get the query executed. `return (T)InnerSession.QueryOver<T>().Where(query).List();`